# Automated/Bot message posting to Microsoft-Teams chat room

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

How can I automatically post messages to chat rooms in Microsoft-Teams? This is for one-way messaging: i.e. posting messages, not reading messages.

The big picture here is we are evaluating different Group Chat solutions, and one requirement is to post error messages to chat rooms from various services & programs.

A sensible approach seems to be to build a [Bot using the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview) however just the [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication) seems crazy complex, even then I can't work out how to just post a message. We're looking for a general solution that can be used simply in different scripting languages (Perl, Python, shell scripts, etc), so we don't want to use the [.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-overview) or [Node.js SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-overview).

We've already looked at Slack and Cisco Spark. Posting messages in both of these is super simple, so I'm hoping there's a similarly simple solution for Microsoft-Teams?!

For example:

In Slack you can use [incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) to post messages. You use the web interface to get a unique webhook URL for each chat room, and then do simple HTTP POST to that URL (with a JSON message payload) to [post to that chat room](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#sending_messages) as the Bot. I had it working in 10 minutes.

In Cisco Spark you [create a Bot](https://developer.ciscospark.com/bots.html) which gives you a unique Access Token. You then get a room_id for the chat room and use those together to do an HTTP POST (again with a JSON payload) to [create a message in the chat room](https://developer.ciscospark.com/endpoint-messages-post.html).

So how do you programmatically post/create/send messages to a chat room in Microsoft-Teams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want is to post a message to a channel using an "Incoming Webhook" connector. For more information, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#setting-up-a-custom-incoming-webhook

Comment: I had to ask our admin to add the "Incoming Webhook" as an available connector, but once this was done the documentation you linked to was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is precisely how the [Office 365 Connectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors) work. A `Connector` allows you to post messages into a Group or Team using web-hooks and a simple JSON payload.

There is a [playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) for playing with these that is super helpful. One note however, there is a bug in the playground's webhook implementation, so for testing purposes, I would stick to the `Send via Email` option. This doesn't affect how these work in production, the bug is isolated to the Playground app itself.